# Parsing through JSON .. Gives undefined?

Tags: json, nested

I have a very complex JSON and a snippet of it is below:

```
var designerJSON= 

{
    "nodes":
 [

        {
            "NodeDefinition": {
                "name": "Start",
                "thumbnail": "Start.png",
                "icon": "Start.png",
                "info": "Entry point ",
                "help": "Start point in your workflow.",
                "workflow ": "Start",
                "category": "Basic",
                "ui": [
                    {
                        "label": "Entry point",
                        "category": "Help",
                        "componet": "label",
                        "type": "label"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "States": [
                {
                    "start": "node1"
                }
            ]
        },.......
]
}
```

I would like to get the value of "start" in States. But I am stuck in the first step of entering into JSON. When I try

```
console.log(designerJSON["nodes"]);
```

I am getting `Undefined`.

I want the value of `start`. Wich is `designerJSON["nodes"]["States"]["start"]`.

Can you help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please use http://json.parser.online.fr/ to validate the json first it may help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have an array in JSON.
instead of

```
designerJSON["nodes"]["States"]["start"]
```

use

```
designerJSON["nodes"][0]["States"][0]["start"]
```

ps. pay attention on how code is formatted in the topic.

pps. using brackets for accessing properties in js is "bad style" (due to js hint recommendations). better access those via dot, e.g:

```
designerJSON.nodes[0].States[0].start
```

Answer (score 0):

`designerJSON["nodes"]["States"]["start"]` won't do it.

`designerJSON["nodes"]` is a list, as is `States`, so you need to access individual items by index (or iteration).

In the example you have given you need to use this:

```
designerJSON['nodes'][0]['States'][0]['start']
```

or this (cleaner IMO):

```
designerJSON.nodes[0].States[0].start
```